# Converting coordinates: Feet to Degrees-Minutes-Seconds

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates

I have a point shapefile and I want to get the coordinates for each point in Degrees-Minutes-Seconds format. When I use [Add XY Coordinates (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000) it gives me the coordinates in Feet format. Any idea/ thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the online help for **[Add XY Coordinates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000)**:

> - If the Input Features are in a geographic coordinate system, POINT_X and POINT_Y represent the longitude and latitude,
>     respectively.
> - If an ArcMap layer is selected as input, the x,y coordinates are based on the input's coordinate system, not that of the data frame.

Check either the dataset that you are using as input, either direct or via a layer, and I expect that you will find it is in a Projected Coordinate System.

If you do not want to **[Project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007m000000)** your data, try using **[Calculate Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000027000000)** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Either your data is projected, or your data frame is projecting on-the-fly...(or both).

Can you verify the input dataset's projection / datum (layer properties > source)?

- If it is using some State Plane system, you may want to make a copy in a geographic projection (e.g. WGS 1984).
- You can also change the data frame properties to project on-the-fly coordinate system to WGS 84 (geographic/world).
- If you need to reproject, use the Data Management / Projections & Transformations / Project Tool with the appropriate datum transformation based on your input points.

Answer (score -1):

Borrowing from PolyGeo..

(Optional to add new fields or change existing x, y fields)
Add two new fields: Lat and Long and make them double precision.
Open the Field Calculator by right clicking on the field (ignore warning message).
For “Lat” field use “y” field.
For “Long” field use “x” field.

Right click on Lat field and select Calculate Geometry (ignore message).
For “Y Coordinate of Point” change units to Decimal Degrees.
Right click on Long field and select Calculate Geometry (ignore message).
For “X Coordinate of Point” change units to Decimal Degrees.

Comment: The OP asked for Degrees Minutes Seconds, this answer was for Decimal Degrees.